# Creating variable which is an interval concisely in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a new variable which is an interval, but as there are many intervals i want to know if i can write the code more concisely. I expect a for loop or a function might do the trick, but for now i have come up with:

```
require(dplyr)    
mtcars %>%
      mutate(
        mpg_interval = if_else(mpg < 15, "<15",
                               if_else(mpg < 20, "15-19",
                                       if_else(mpg < 25, "20-24", 
                                               ">24")))
      )
```

Is there an easier way to make many intervals (i.e. 100, which would be impractical to write out) using `dplyr` commands?

Comment: you can try [cut](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/cut)

Comment: To elaborate on Aramis comment, you can use an array to define your intervals like this `mpg_interval = cut(mpg,c(0,5,10,15,20,25,Inf)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Aramis7d and @Florian point out in the comments above, `cut` is the tool for the job.  If the number of intervals is too long to write out, then `cut` can be used with `seq`.

Consider

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100)
df %>% mutate(rg=cut(x,c(seq(0, 25, 5), Inf))) %>%
  group_by(rg) %>% summarise(c = n())
# A tibble: 6 × 2
        rg     c
    <fctr> <int>
1    (0,5]     5
2   (5,10]     5
3  (10,15]     5
4  (15,20]     5
5  (20,25]     5
6 (25,Inf]    75
```

Answer (score 5):

I think what you need is `case_when()`:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    mpg_interval = case_when(
      mpg < 15 ~ "<15",
      mpg < 20 ~ "15-19",
      mpg < 25 ~ "20-24", 
      TRUE     ~ ">24"
    )
  )
```

Comment: What about if i have a lot of cases, i.e. 100, which would be unpractical to write down, is there a way to use `seq()`?

Comment: Actually, when you have a lot of cases, I think the best way to do it would be to construct a correspondence table.